# MCP73831T-2ACI Not Terminating Charging

Tags: battery-charging

I have the following charging circuit which I've connected to a 12000mAh PiJuice battery ~ https://uk.pi-supply.com/products/pijuice-12000mah-battery. In addition, and not shown here, I have hooked up a MAX17048G to act as a fuel gauge.

I am able to charge the battery just fine (I saw it go from ~50% up to ~100% overnight, charging w/~450mA). The issue is that the STAT LED never goes off. I'm measuring STAT = 0.26v, and VBAT 4.206v. It seems like STAT should go high at some point, but after a few hours of hovering at 100%, the LED is still on.

Only thing I can think of is that I need one of the other variants of the chip with different termination current ratio setting.

Any ideas?

[image]

Adding here for the sake of completeness, the Fuel Gauge chip shows it at ~100.3% full and 4.19v).

Fuel gauge schematic (which shouldn't come into play, I'm just using it as a data source) is below:

[image]

Comment: If you have some unknown connections to some fuel gauge chip, there is no way we can comment on why your battery never stops charging. Show the full circuit. Does it work without the custom fuel gauge chip?

Comment: I don't believe the fuel gauge is implicated here, I'm just using it to keep an eye on the operation, but I've added the schematic in case it's helpful.

Comment: Is anything else connected to the battery at all? Any kind of load or anything else?

Comment: Yes, there's a light load (ESP32s3 processor).

Comment: Failure to provide all the available and necessary information, in the question, makes the question close to unanswerable. We need to know the percentage of max current termination point and the magnitude of the current that is drawn by the load and other random devices and the current which is actually being delivered by the IC when it "fails to stop"

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but the first of those three is per the data sheet for the specific device, and the last of the three is also per the data sheet with the specific resistor r17,  no?

Comment: So current delivered by the IC is 417mA, current drawn by the load is 100-200mA (my estimate based on how fast the battery is charging), and the Iterm/Ireg is 7.5 per the data sheet (less clear on what this means)

Comment: Check the condition of the pijuice battery. Batteries can degrade, and impact the charging circuit's behavior.